# Wait for UI text to be updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

As part of our application a user can click on an item in a list, this then changes a load of data on the screen, included the text on a filter button.

for example a list may be cities
London
New York
Tokyo

clicking on London will change the filter label from 'All' to '1' intially while we wait for an angular controller to work out what teh correct text should be from our api, then it changes to 'London' there is a slight delay on this while the angular controllers work out what the correct label should be and while the rest of the page loads more data from our api.

This delay causes tests in protractor to fail because the delay is just long enough for protractor to pick up '1' as the text rather than 'London', putting in a sleep for a second solves this but this action is performed a lot through testing and don't want to sleep each time, is there a way i can wait for an angular controller to finish or something so i end up waiting just the right amount of time?

I know protractor waits for angular normally but i'm thinking the initial change of the label from 'All' to '1' is fooling protractor into thinking its ready to continue, since its all done through multiple angular controllers and services

Thanks

Comment: Please create a  fiddle with a basic example of what you are trying to obtain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explicitly wait for the London text to appear. This method was shown to me a couple of days ago, and it's been quite useful since.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

// Replace below with whatever locator is appropriate for your case
var elem = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'London')]"));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elem), 5000);
expect(elem.isPresent()).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: This actually is exactly what i need. i'm assuming that where you have var ER you mean var EC? Also i will mark as correct as soon as i get a chance to try it.

Comment: Oh yeah, ER is supposed to be EC. Dunno where the R came from.

Comment: Hey i just get the error Cannot call method 'presenceOf' of undefined not sure why. Debugging always shows EC as undefined i have declared it like this var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions im guessing that hsould work, i also updated to latest protractor earlier today so im assuming it should work

Comment: That's odd, haven't encountered that myself :| [Here's a link to expectedconditions docs](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) though, hopefully that'll help you. Just try and check for typos at least, other than that no idea.

Comment: Its OK i sorted it, the update of protractor i did earlier messed up somewhere so i just got it again to make sure and it worked, so it was my fault.